# jQuery alternative for addEventListener for custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on clicking event script and i need jquery alternative for js addEvetListener for custom attribute.

Here is my js version which does not work and i need jquery alternative:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-slide-number]').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(item.getAttribute("data-slide-number"));
  })
})
```

I need to listen to all elements with **data-slide-number** attributes so i can use click function on them.

I tried this but its not working:

```
$('[data-slide-number]').on( "click", function(event) {

    alert( $( this ).html() );
    console.log( event.target );

} );
```

And i need to add listener because im trying to execute these functions while clicking on another elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#desat', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="9"]').click(); 
});

$(document).on('click', '#jedenast', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).html());
    $('[data-slide-number="10"]').click(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-slide-number]', function(){
      let _number = $(this).data('slide-number');
      slideTo(_number);
});
```